# SSRS - IIF error in Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, null

I am having an issue with a divide by zero error that I have half way worked through.

Basically I need (EstimatedValuePlanned - EAC) / EstimatedValuePlanned

I have the following, however I am still getting #Error on some:

```
= IIF (Fields!EstimatedValuePlanned.Value = 0 , 0, 
Fields!EstimatedValuePlanned.Value - Fields!EAC.Value) 
/ 
SUM(Fields!EstimatedValuePlanned.Value)
```

I have changed the code around several times but I still either get Error or NaN

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that both fields are numeric? I tried to reporo same and can't see any issue with that.

Comment: Both EstimatedValuePlanned and EAC are numeric returns from SQL and not formulas. The field I am working in is set to Percent. If EstimatedValuePlanned = 4195 and EAC = 1500 then my field returns 64.24%, however if EstimatedValuePlanned = 0 and EAC = 85 then my field shows #Error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIF will always evaluate both parts of the function, so when `SUM(Fields!EstimatedValuePlanned.Value)` is zero you will get the error even though that's not what will be returned.

Try using a `SWITCH` statement. `SWITCH` stops once an expression returns `True`.

Something like this

```
= SWITCH(
SUM(Fields!EstimatedValuePlanned.Value) = 0 , 0, 
True, (Fields!EstimatedValuePlanned.Value - Fields!EAC.Value) / SUM(Fields!EstimatedValuePlanned.Value)
)
```

The `True` expression simply acts like an `else`

**UPDATE WITH SAMPLE**
I created a new report added a dataset and set the dataset query to be the following (just to generate some dummy data).

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (EVP float, EAC float)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1,2),
(2,3),
(5,4),
(0,2),
(1,0),
(0,0)

SELECT * FROM @t
```

I then added a table, set the first to columns to be EVP and EAC respectively and set the 3rd column to an expression as follows.

```
=SWITCH (
Fields!EVP.Value = 0, 0
, True, (Fields!EVP.Value - Fields!EAC.Value) / Fields!EVP.Value
)
```

The report design looks like this.

[image]

And when it's run this is the result....

[image]

Try replicating the above steps and see if you can get it to work like this first then review difference to your report.

Comment: Thanks Alan, However when my EstimatedValuePlanned = 0 then I still get the error Example if it is 0 and EAC is 85 - I end up with -85/0 which is not possible so the error returns.

Comment: In your original post your expression checked the single row value of `EstimatedValuePlanned` but then the calcualtion was based on the `SUM` of `EstimatedValuePlanned`. I assumed that was a typo and changed it as it didn't make any sense. If you only need to calculate at the row level then change `SUM(Fields!EstimatedValuePlanned.Value)` and replace with just `Fields!EstimatedValuePlanned.Value` in both instances.

Comment: Sorry SUM was just one of my many many attempts :)  Yes this will be just on the row level, I tried the below but still get the #error It seems that IIF and SWITCH are still trying to divide by 0.......= SWITCH(Fields!EstimatedValuePlanned.Value = 0 , 0, 
True, (Fields!EstimatedValuePlanned.Value - Fields!EAC.Value) / Fields!EstimatedValuePlanned.Value
)

Comment: I'll edit the answer to show a sample. This should work... Give me 10 mins

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with:

```
=IIF  (Fields!EstimatedValuePlanned.Value = 0 , 0, 
Fields!EstimatedValuePlanned.Value - Fields!EAC.Value) 
/ 
IIF(Fields!EstimatedValuePlanned.Value = 
0,1,Fields!EstimatedValuePlanned.Value)
```

Thank you both

Comment: not elegant but if you are happy that's what counts ! :)